# Problem in book Art of Problem?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers, such that $a \mid b^2$, $b^2 \mid a^3$, $a^3 \mid b^4$, 
$b^4 \mid a^5\ldots$.

Prove that $a = b$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please note, for further reference, the $\LaTeX$ editing I did to the text of your question.

Comment: Can you add your thoughts about the problem and tell where you're stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$, $b=p_1^{s_1}\cdots p_m^{s_m}$ - factorizations of $a$ and $b$, in primes, where $r_i,s_i\ge 0$ integers.

Then $a^k|b^{k+1}|a^{k+2}$ implies that $$kr_j\le (k+1)s_j\le (k+2)r_j,$$ for all $j$'s and $k=1,\ldots,$ which can be satisfied only if $r_j=s_j$, for all $j$.